# Junit Testing @getmappings with h2 in memory database

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I'm having issues unit testing the DbRequest controller.  I have one unit test working, but I'm unable to achieve a unit test for the DBRequest controller GET mappings which does a database lookup using hibernate. I' have an H2 in memory database created for the junit tests.
I've tried a variety of different setups, and nothing seems to work correctly.

Edited the below, I'm getting a NullPointer,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.lmig.informaticaservice.api.DBcontroltest.saveTest(DBcontroltest.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Here is the edited test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest

@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class DBcontroltest {



@Autowired
DbRequest dbRequest;


    @Autowired
    ConnectionRequestRepository connectionRequestRepository;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    // @Autowired
   //private TestEntityManager entityManager;



     @Test
    public void saveTest() throws Exception {
         ConnectionRequest connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest((long) 1, "test");
         connectionRequestRepository.save(connectionRequest);


         System.out.println(connectionRequestRepository.findAll().toString());

         mockMvc.perform(get("/api/selectDB/{connectionId}" ,1))
                 .andExpect(status().isOk());


    }

}


Typical JPA repository 

    package com.test.models;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

    public interface ConnectionRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<ConnectionRequest, Long> {

    }
```

Here is my controller.

```
package com.test.api;

import com.models.ConnectionRequest;
import com.test.models.ConnectionRequestRepository;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import lombok.Data;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Data
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class DbRequest {

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionRequestRepository connectionRequestRepository;
    private ConnectionRequest connectionRequest;

    @GetMapping("/selectDB")
    public List<ConnectionRequest> getAllRequests() {
        return connectionRequestRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/selectDB/{connectionId}")
    public ResponseEntity<ConnectionRequest> getRequestById(@PathVariable("connectionId") Long connectionId) throws Exception {
        ConnectionRequest connectionRequest = connectionRequestRepository.findById(connectionId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Connection Request " + connectionId + " not found"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(connectionRequest);
    }
}
```

Here is the model for the database.

```
package com.testing.models;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "connrequest", schema = "testschema")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class ConnectionRequest {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "connection_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long connectionId;

    @Column(name = "requestor", nullable = false)
    private String requestor;
}
```

Comment: You aren't testing your controller but rather only your repository. So not sure how this question is related to testing your controller?

Comment: I was able to test the repo, I'm not sure how I would test that controller, while using the repository code successfully.  Anything I've read does not seem to work with get mappings.

Comment: Your repository test is flawed so although it might work it is flawed. You want a full integration test so use an `@SpringBootTest` annotation for the controller test. If you want only the controller and mock the dependencies use `@WebMvcTest` to only test the web related part.

Comment: Flawed in what way?   That it does not provide a full integration test?

Comment: You are mixing `@DataJpaTest` (a slices) with a full config using `@ContextConfiguration`. Use one or the other, not both.

Comment: removed @ContextConfiguration.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've made some edits.  Do you know why I'd be getting that nullpointer possibly?

Comment: You aren't autowiring `MockMvc`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the on of the annotations on the PK of `ConnectionRequest` is the problem.

The annotation `@GeneratedValue` tells JPA that it needs to determine the value, so any provided value for the ID will be actively discarded. From the docs

> Indicates that the persistence provider **must assign primary keys** for the entity using a database identity column.

To fix this try either removing that annotation, so then you **must** always provide an `ID`, or alternatively, after saving the entity in your test, get the `ID` that is assigned and call `connectionRequestRepository.getOne()` with that `ID`.